# Using present perfect tense with "today"

Tags: present-perfect, time

Can I use the present perfect tense with *this week*, *this month*, *this year*, or *today*?

For example,

> I've spoken to her today.
>
> She's been in Paris this year.

Comment: As long as the speaker considers the time period he mentions (whether *today*, *this week*, *this month*, *this year*...also *tonight*, *this evening*, *this morning*, etc) to not be over, then yes you can, and the examples you give are common uses.

Comment: It is possible to consider *today* as being *over*, in which case the present perfect would not be natural. See [When a sentence includes a word like 'today' that indicates present time, can a past form of verb be used?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74351/when-a-sentence-includes-a-word-like-today-that-indicates-present-time-can-a).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the present perfect with current periods of time such as **today** and **this week**, providing there may be more opportunities to do the same action.

Examples:

(Game is in progress):  **I've caught** five passes today (**so far** or **up to now**).  (You may have more chances to catch a pass.)

(Game is over):  **I caught** five passes today. (There is no chance you can catch any more passes, since the game has ended.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it mean that English Tenses usage depends strictly on the moment or period of time? I'm not sure I understand all situations where P.Perfect can be used.

Comment: @Marita Have you seen *[How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846)*

Comment: @Marita: I'm afraid the answer to your question is "No". In some circumstances, only the past can be used, or only the perfect can be used. But  often, either may be used to refer to exactly the same circumstance, the difference being in how the speaker is choosing to relate events temporally. If I say _I've seen him today_, I am expressing (as well as the fact that I did see him) that this is somehow relevant to the present time; but the nature of that relevance is unspecified. Perhaps I had an instruction to see him by the end of today, for example.

Comment: In  all English textbooks P.Perfect is refered as a result of some activity in the past or goes together with certain adverbs.

Comment: So if I say "I've spoken to my cousin today" does it mean that the day lasts and I may speak to her once more?

Comment: Yes, generally, when the period of time has not yet ended, and the opportunity exists to do the same thing again before that time period ends, you would use that construction.

Comment: It's ok,thank you. And if I say "I never said that" or "I've never said that" which is the difference in the meaning?

Comment: The difference is small.  If you can add "up to now" or "so far" to your sentence, it's better to use the second example.  In other words, when there is a chance you might still do it, use the present perfect.  However, in everyday use, the two are practically the same.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think  present perfect is the most difficult tense to understand and use for non-natives.

Comment: And can I use "ever" or " since" with past simple?

Comment: In casual speech, both forms are used.  When asking about experiences, you would use present perfect: "Have you ever gone skydiving?"  "Have you ever been in love?"  But the simple past can be used when asking about whether you've done something that was planned:  "Did you ever speak to your husband about coming to our dinner party?"  Strangely, you could also use present perfect here, but usually, without "ever":  "Have you spoken to your husband about coming to our dinner party?"  May I ask, what is your first language?

Comment: I always noticed that native speakers use p.perfect and p.simple with both adverbs. It's interesting but in English grammar books for non-natives tenses are explained together with adverbs, for example  ever with present perfect and last with past simple.

Comment: My first language is Armenian but my education is in Russian. Is it significant?

Comment: It would be significant to me if I were familiar with your language and I could make comparisons.  Unfortunately, I am not familiar with either Armenian or Russian, so it doesn't help me help you.  About your comment about grammar books, these books are always oversimplified.  They'd have to be, or they'd all be 2000 pages long.

Comment: The most popular English  textbook now  is New English File by Oxford. Russian is absolutely different by its structure,by its way of thinking. It has lots of prefixes,suffixes,endings  the coincidence of adjective and noun according to the grammar case and gender. There's no to be in present in Russian,the structure of sentence is so that to be is not used. The articulation is also quite different that's why  it's really difficult for Russians to learn any western language.

Comment: And Armenian is a contrast to both Russian and English. It's one of the most ancient oriental languages in the world,it has 39 letters, cases, coincidence of words and difficult pronunciation as there're 3 types of r,3 types of h,  3 t. of g and so on

Comment: @Colin Fine "I'm afraid the answer to your question is "No".  Is this the question you're referring to? :  "Does it mean that English Tenses usage depends strictly on the moment or period of time? "

Comment: @anouk: yes, that is the question I was responding to.